# Difference between width() and css(width)

Tags: jquery

I am using JQuery to set the width of a region with `id="mydiv"`. When I use

```
$(‘#mydiv’).width(300px);
```

the region is styled incorrectly, but when I use

```
$(‘#mydiv’).css(‘width’,’300px’);
```

the style is correctly rendered.  Both .width() and .css() are listed in http://api.jquery.com.  Why the difference?

Comment: "Note that .width() will always return the content width, regardless of the value of the CSS box-sizing property." http://api.jquery.com/width/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe because you are missing quotes

```
$(‘#mydiv’).width("300px");
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference lies in datatype. As its clear in code that with css method you need to append 'px' to the width value and with width you don't need to specify.

When you want to read width of any element then css method will return you string value like '100px' while width will return an integer value.

```
alert($('#mydiv').css('width'));
```

This return *'100px'*.

```
alert($('#mydiv').width());
```

This returns *100*.

So if you want to do any kind of manipulation then width function is the best option.